# Why is this list item being styled with element.style instead of my custom style?

Tags: css

I have an unordered list that I'm using as a menu. It has a nested list in order to accommodate sub-items:

```
<ul class="menu" id="sub_menu">
  <li class="item452"><a href="/tfidev/about-us">About Us</a></li>
  <li class="item453"><a href="/tfidev/leadership">Leadership</a></li>
  <li id="current" class="parent active item454"><a href="/tfidev/press-room">Press Room</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="item455"><a href="/tfidev/press-room/press-releases">Press Releases</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item456"><a href="/tfidev/community-resources">Community Resources</a></li>
  <li class="item457"><a href="/tfidev/careers">Careers</a></li>
</ul>
```

The nested list item is not displaying (the Press Releases item), and when I do an Inspect Element, this is what I get:

[image]

Can anyone tell my why the element.style of display:none is overriding the matched css rule of display:block?

*EDITED - !important added; no change**

[image]

Comment: Are there scripts that might be adding inline styles?  Perhaps you're using jQuery on the page?

Comment: There is jquery, yes, but I'm not sure where I'd find element.style. I've search all of the linked stylesheets, and can't find anything that would set that particular element to display:none.

Comment: It's in the Javascript code somewhere.  Look for `.js` files or `<script>` blocks.

Comment: I found a number of references to .css in the js file for an accordion  slideshow on our home page, but nothing that should affect this menu (which is not on the home page.) However, I set the js file to be conditionally loaded depending on whether it's the home page or not (this is a Joomla template, so you have one index.php file that contains code for all pages), and now it's getting the correct style. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline styles override stylesheet declarations. "element.style" shows you the current inline styles. These were probably set via JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

It must be added via javascript.
Have a look at your javascript file, and look for:

```
.css
```

or

```
.style
```

It should be one of the above that is modifying the element and therefore overwriting your CSS.